# Display two images in didFinishPickingImage - iOS Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, image, uiimageview, swift2, uiimagepickercontroller

I have two `UIImageView`s, each with two buttons. One button takes a picture and the other chooses a photo from a library. Both buttons work correctly. But when I choose an image by a button from the first sheet, it is displayed in both `UIImageView`s. My question is how can we display the image in only the corresponding `ImageView`?.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) {
    print("Image Selected")
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    importedImage.image = image
    secondPhoto.image = image
}

// MARK: - Action Sheet


@IBAction func showActionSheet1(sender: AnyObject) {
    let image = UIImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self
    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Action Sheet", message: "Choose Option", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
    let libButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Select from photo library", style: .Default, handler: { (libButton) -> Void in
        image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        image.allowsEditing = false

        self.presentViewController(image, animated: true, completion: nil)

    })
    let cameraButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Take picture", style: .Default, handler: { (cameraButton) -> Void in

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera){

        image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        image.allowsEditing = false
        self.presentViewController(image, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    })
    let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: {(cancelButton) -> Void in
        print("Cancel selected")
    })
    actionSheet.addAction(libButton)
    actionSheet.addAction(cameraButton)
    actionSheet.addAction(cancelButton)


    self.presentViewController(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

@IBAction func showActionSheet2(sender: AnyObject) {

    let image = UIImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self

    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Action Sheet", message: "Choose Option", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
    let libButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Select from photo library", style: .Default, handler: { (libButton) -> Void in
        image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        image.allowsEditing = false
        self.presentViewController(image, animated: true, completion: nil)

    })
    let cameraButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Take picture", style: .Default, handler: { (cameraButton) -> Void in

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera){

            image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
            image.allowsEditing = false
            self.presentViewController(image, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    })
    let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: {(cancelButton) -> Void in
        print("Cancel selected")
    })
    actionSheet.addAction(libButton)
    actionSheet.addAction(cameraButton)
    actionSheet.addAction(cancelButton)


    self.presentViewController(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Use a global reference to the imageView you want to changed; in the action sheet functions, set that variable to the desired imageView.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Problem solved. I have add the var imageInput: UIImageView!. Inside the action sheet before presentViewController, I set "self.imageInput = self.importedImage". In the didFinishPickingImage method, I change to "input.image = image"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are setting image in both the `ImageView` inside `didFinishPickingImage`, to solve the issue need to maintain some state like which `Button` is clicked to set `Image`, for that you can create one `Bool` instance and assign its value inside the action of Button like this.

```
var isFromFirst: Bool = false

@IBAction func showActionSheet1(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.isFromFirst = true
    ...//your other code

}

@IBAction func showActionSheet2(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.isFromFirst = false
    ...//your other code

}
```

After that check this bool value inside `didFinishPickingImage` like this.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) {
    print("Image Selected")
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    if (self.isFromFirst) {
        importedImage.image = image
    }
    else {
        secondPhoto.image = image
    }
}
```